# how do i identify a word within a cell in order to trigger an action

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a set of spreadsheets with lots of redundant columns. I want to hide all columns who's header Includes the word "mark" (rather than = "mark".  And get the same thing to happen on ALL sheets in the file

I can identify the columns using a match and a helper cell, I know how to hide cells, its hiding according to cell content - a word within a sentence, and checking a variable range of columns.  I have based code on several similar but also quite different examples on this site

```
function hideColumn() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get first sheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // get data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange();

  // get number of columns
  var lastCol = data.getLastColumn()+1;

  Logger.log(lastCol);

  // itterate through columns
  for(var i=1; i<lastCol; i++) {
     if(data.getCell(1, i).match() ("mark"))
    {
        sheet.hideColumns(i);
     }
  }
}
```

im getting function match in object range error.

Answer (score 1):

This function allows you to use regular expressions in your search if you wish to. It also assumes the header row is 1 and the default search string is "mark".  It will search through all sheets in the spreadsheet using the same defaults in each sheet. Of course you can edit the defaults as you prefer.

```
function hideColumnsInWhichHeaderContainsString(headerRow,string,useregex) {
  var useregex=useregex||false;
  var headerRow=headerRow||1;
  var string=string||"mark";
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    var sh=shts[i];
    var rg=sh.getRange(headerRow,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
    var rgA=rg.createTextFinder(string).useRegularExpression(useregex).matchCase(true).findAll();
    for(var j=0;j<rgA.length;j++) {
      sh.hideColumns(rgA[j].getColumn());
    }    
  }
}
```

I performed only limited testing on it.

The below function is working on data that I copied from your sheet.

```
function hideColumnsInWhichHeaderContainsString1(setupA) {
  var setupA=setupA || [{headerRow:1,string:"Mark",useregex:false,matchcase:true,visibility:"hide"},{headerRow:1,string:"MILESTONES",useregex:true,matchcase:false,visibility:"hide"},{headerRow:1,string:"MILESTONES- Grade",useregex:false,matchcase:true,visibility:"show"}];
  if(setupA.length>0) {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var shts=ss.getSheets();
    for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
      var sh=shts[i];
      for(var k=0;k<setupA.length;k++) {
        var rg=sh.getRange(setupA[k].headerRow,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
        var rgA=rg.createTextFinder(setupA[k].string).useRegularExpression(setupA[k].useregex).matchCase(setupA[k].matchcase).findAll();
        for(var j=0;j<rgA.length;j++) {
          if(setupA[k].visibility=="hide") {
            sh.hideColumns(rgA[j].getColumn());
          }else{
            sh.showColumns(rgA[j].getColumn());
          }
        }    
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Regular Expression Reference](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199128/discussion-on-answer-by-cooper-how-do-i-identify-a-word-within-a-cell-in-order-t).

Comment: wait for a moderator to move the comments to chat, as that grants all prior participants access